# Creating a Class Mathematical Function

Tags: java, function

Hey so what I'm trying to do currently is a function plotter. To do that I want to have a class Function which, so far looks as this:

```
public class Function implements IFunction{

private C instruction; //C is a placeholder for the answer to my question

public Function(C instruction){
    this.instruction = instruction;//Instructions is supposed to be 
}                                  //something that tells the programm hot
@Override                          //calculate Y from x.
public double getY(double x) {
    return this.instruction(x) //using the instructions

}
```

My question now is, which data structur could I use to represent my Instructions. Because a function can have all kinds of isntructions from y = sin(x) to y = x and I want to be able to assign each function the fitting instruction.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should probably take a look at the built in functional interfaces ( like function, bifunction, supplier, etc) in Java 8. It looks like you are asking about implementing a non generic version of those.

Comment: Why do you need this `Function` class? Do you need such an adapter, or can `C` just implement `IFunction` directly?

Comment: Maybe it could. But my goal was to implement Functions in such a way, that every instance that is created has the instructions as an attribut.

Comment: Functions are not first class citizens in Java; as described, this is going to be tough